# Turn javascript into toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this javascipt and html:

```js
function flipTXT(rotate) {
    if (parent_window && !parent_window.closed) {
        parent_window.document.getElementById("teleprompter")
            .style.webkitTransform = rotate;
    }
}
```

```html
<li>
    <a class="button small icon-text-width flipx" href="#"
       onClick="javascript:flipTXT('rotateY(180deg)')")></a>
</li>
```

What it does is allows me to click a button on a popup page and set the text on a parent page to be mirrored . The problem is that it only works once.

How would i make it so that when the button is cliked again it sets it to `rotateY(0deg)`.

Or make it a toggle.

Comment: Toggle an additional class, which performs the rotation.

Comment: @Blazemonger  How ? It took me forever to figure out that javascript above

Answer (score 2):

Toggle an additional class, which performs the rotation.

CSS:

```
.flipped { transform: rotateY(180deg); }
```

JS:

```
$('#teleprompter').toggleClass('flipped');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/4pru4hap/

Comment: @JuanMendes Do i just add this onto my javascript of replace the line with this . Will this work in the parent child system I am using?

Comment: I can't give you a complete solution because your code uses variables like `parent_window` that I don't know what they are. If you provided a working demo of your code on http://jsfiddle.net I might be able to help you further.

Comment: @Blazemonger parent_window is a var that equals window.opener

Comment: @JamieAdamas Add jQuery and the CSS to the parent window. Your script in the popup should be `parent_window.$('#teleprompter').toggleClass('flipped')`

Comment: @Blazemonger  I have jquery-1.10.1.min.js and I have the css in a stylesheet that both the parent and child can acces and i have the script <script>
function flipTXT()
 {
        parent_window.$('#teleprompter').toggleClass('flipx');
 }
</script>     but it dosent work

Comment: @Blazemonger I have it like in your demo , except i have the parent window thing before the $. It dosent do anything . Would it be helpfull if you had my code